# Knockout.js click binding with arguments

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js, data-binding

Let's say I have function defined in a viewmodel like:

```
self.calculate = function(a,b) {
   .
   .
   .
}
```

On the other hand, I have an html code like:

`<p id="value1">5</p>
 <p id="value2">8</p>
 <p data-bind="click: calculate(...,...)"></p>`

So my question is: can I pass **"value1"** and **"value2"** as a parameters in the calculate function, since it's bind on click and is defined in a viewmodel?
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of passing values to calculate function, you can also data bind value1 and value2 to view model, then use then in your calculate method.